# I want to add more than one wishlist to one transaction

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm making e-commerce website using Laravel, where is selling animals like cow, sheep, goat, etc.

In my wishlist table there is field user_id, animal, grade, and weight.

I want to make transaction table, where have field user_id, wishlist_id, totalPrice, and Verification.

The problem is let say I have 3 wishlist, and I already got the totalPrice. If I want to pay all of the wishlist, what happen to the transaction table.

Will it shows like this?
[image: Transaction Table]

Or what?

Note : The verification is for if the user send the payment notation, and admin already look up and it validate, then it will show true or Verified.

What i want is if I want to pay all the wishlist and just making one transaction with the totalPrice of the total wishlist Price. (Just one field used)

Here,s my wishlist blade code :

```
@php
 $totalHarga = 0;
@endphp

@foreach ($keranjang->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id) as $item)
 <li>
  <div class="media-left">
   <div class="cart-img"> 
    <a href="/{{ $item->hewan }}" class="margin-0">
     <img class="media-object img-responsive" src="{{ $item->img }}" alt="..."> 
    </a> 
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="media-body">
   <h6 class="media-heading">{{ $item->hewan }}×{{ $item->qty }}</h6>
   @foreach ($bobot->where('bobot', $item->bobot) as $items)
    <span class="price">Rp {{ number_format( $items->harga ) }}</span> 
    <span class="qty">Bobot : {{ $item->bobot }} ({{ $item->grade }})</span>
    <form action="{{ route('items.destroy', $item->id) }}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     @method('delete')
     <button type="submit" class="btn-danger padding-left-5 padding-right-5">Delete</button>
    </form>
    @php
     $harga = $items->harga;
     $harga *= $item->qty;
     $totalHarga += $harga;
    @endphp
   @endforeach
 </div>
</li>
@endforeach

<li>
 <h5 class="text-center">SUBTOTAL : Rp {{ number_format($totalHarga) }}</h5>
</li>
<li class="margin-0">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10  margin-left-20">
   <a href="/bayars" class="btn">CHECK OUT</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
```

Note : hewan is Animals, harga is Price, bobot is Weight, grade is Grade, and keranjang is Wishlist (Just a language from Indonesia)

Comment: Can you redefine the Transaction table? If I understood the issue properly, this is just a matter of data modeling. It seems that you want each transaction to represent a single check-out event, regardless of how many wishlists were included in the final order. Is that what you want?

Comment: @EduardoPacheco Exactly what I want! I already got the totalPrice calculation of them. I want to make it like what you said. Help me brother 

Comment: Can you share the code on which you iterate over the wishlists and populate the transaction table?

Comment: @EduardoPacheco I already edit the question and add my wishlist blade. For the Transaction Table is only assumed by me, i haven't make it yet because awared of this problem. Can you help me to solve this and recommend the table of Transaction field please?

Answer (score 0):

How your transaction table will look like is up to you and there ain't a "correct" way of doing it - although there are definitely wrong ways. It all comes down to what schema best fits your needs. That being said, I'll propose some data modeling alternatives here.

The starting point is: **You want to track your Check-out transactions.** One way to model it would be calling your transaction table `"checkouts"` with fields:

```
TABLE checkouts
    bigint   id,
    bigint   user_id,
    float    total_price,
    boolean  verification
```

Now, we also need to keep track of what `wishlists` are contained within the check-out. This seems to be a `1..N` relationship (one checkout has many wishlists), and we can implement it by adding a `checkout_id` field to `"wishlists"` table.

- The new field should be `nullable`;
- Wishlists are created with `checkout_id` set to null;
- Once checked out, they are set to the checkout id.

With this schema we have a single row on the `"checkout"` table representing the transaction of the wishlists, while `"wishlists"` table are grouping the items (or animals) themselves. I suppose the schema would be something like:

```
TABLE checkouts
    bigint   id,
    -- bigint user_id, (we can take it from wishlists)
    float    total_price,
    boolean  verification

TABLE wishlists
    bigint   id,
    bigint   user_id,
    bigint   checkout_id nullable

TABLE item_wishlist
    bigint   wishlist_id,
    bigint   item_id

TABLE items
    bigint   id,
    float    price,
    -- etc.
```

This schema assumes the `"checkouts"` are composed of `"wishlists"`, and it must be adapted depending on other business rules.